# No audio Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound

I have no audio on my desktop pc.

```
marco@MARCO-PC:~$ uname -a
Linux MARCO-PC 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26 19:39:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

marco@MARCO-PC:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7120000 irq 125

marco@MARCO-PC:~$ lspci | grep -i audio 
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
```

I checked audio controls are not muted

```
marco@MARCO-PC:~$ aplay -l
**** Lista di PLAYBACK dispositivi hardware ****
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sottoperiferiche: 0/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Check is your volume turned all the way down, or is your speaker muted:

Click on the speaker icon in the upper right hand corner of the screen. This will launch a drop down menu which has a slider to control the volume. Make sure that the volume is not set too low.

2.Check is your speakers connected correctly:

When connecting speakers to the back of the computer, connect the speakers to the Line Out or Sound Out port, which is usually a light green port.

3.Choose your correct PORT (device) in Pulseaudo properties.

Left click (or right in Xubuntu if you using Alsamixer) on the speacker icon in the upper right hand corner of the screen. This will launch a drop down menu. Choose Sound Settings (or Properties in Xubuntu).
It will open Volume Conctrol.
Open Output Devices tab and select correct device in "Port" to be output source.
For eg. Bulid in analog-stereo, HDA NVidia, Speakers... 
Then set it to 100%.

Same thing in Input Devices tab to set microphone or line etc. to be your input source.

For HDMI audio select the HDMI profile (or something like: Digital audio (HDMI) Output, HDMI/Dyslpay port...) in the Configuration tab of the Volume Control.

[image]

Please give more infomation.

```
aplay -l
lspci | grep VGA
```

With headphones or speakers plugged in, run the following utility for testing:

for analog output

```
speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,0
```

or for digital output

```
speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,1
```

With the HDMI cable plugged in, run the following utility for testing:

```
speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,3
```

if you don't hear the test sound try next device

```
speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,7
```

and

```
speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,8
```

(Explanation: the  hw:x,y  is  x = card, y = device)

This just runs a sound test with static bouncing back and forth. Once it has played out of each speaker, hit Ctrl+c to stop it, and then check in your sound settings to see if the HDMI output is now listed under the internal device.
Or: `aplay -D plughw:0,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`

If does not output any errors, but still no sound is heared, "reboot" the receiver, monitor or tv set. Since the HDMI interface executes a handshake on connection, it might have noticed before that there was no audio stream embedded, and disabled audio decoding.

If that don't work, do this:
1. Connect your TV or external monitor through HDMI while you are using Ubuntu.
2.Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and use the following command

```
pulseaudio -k
```

3.Now, open Sound Settings again. You should see the option of HDMI in the Output tab.

PS. Same procedure whit headphones or speakers.

Comment: I have no external devices of output. I want to play sounds on hearphones and HDMI monitor. All other options in configurations are signed as "unplugged", I've checked HDMI displays

Comment: Try to select the HDMI profile (or something like that)  in the configuration tab of the  Volume Control

Comment: Do you have dualboot Ubuntu with Windows 8 or 10?

Comment: No only Ubuntu is installed. 
Tried all solutions listed but nothing seems to work.  Here the lspci
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)

Comment: But I am interested primarily on hearphones, no matter if HDMI does not will work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,ubuntu 20 was not dectecting the input/output audio devices.
By running "pulseaudio" in a terminal it started working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ubuntu 20 would be a version of Ubuntu Core not what the OP asked about.